# Change value of an iframe .. php hook?

Tags: php, html, iframe, input, hook

I have an iframe inside my php file when I click certain button, the new iframe window has an input text that i have to write some numbers.
This one

`<input data-v-3605879a="" name="custom-field-0" placeholder="id (required)" id="custom-field-0" type="number" class="form-control is-invalid" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">`

How I can make the input text to have the same default value? Because if I use value="25" for example, it doesnt work and 25 is not sent as the value of that input box

Comment: You need to provide more information. Setting the value to 25 for input type number should normally do the job.

Comment: It should work, but isn’t working. Maybe some javascript is blocking it unless you literally type in the input box?

Comment: Possibly, it's a blind guess now, you'd have to provide more information, is it publicly available?

Comment: Yes, this is the js [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alesyt0h/YouTube-Android/master/vendor.js)